# Animations not working using scene2d and actor class in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I have a problem making a simple animation using the Actor class.

```
public class fondoanima extends Actor {

protected TextureRegion currentFrame;
protected TextureRegion[] walkFrames;
protected Animation walkAnimation, idleAnimation, currentAnimation;
private Texture texture;
float stateTime;


public fondoanima() {

    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("image.png"));
    TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(texture, texture.getWidth()/5, texture.getHeight() / 1);

    walkFrames = new TextureRegion[5];
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        walkFrames[j] = tmp[0][j];
    }

    walkAnimation = new Animation(0.4f, walkFrames);
    currentAnimation = walkAnimation;

    stateTime = 0f;   

    }

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

    Color col = getColor();
    batch.setColor(col.r, col.g, col.b, col.a*parentAlpha);
        batch.draw(currentFrame, 10, 10);

}

@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.act(delta);

         stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); 
        currentFrame = currentAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
}

public void dispose(){}
```

I have been guided by different examples and the wiki, But I get not make it work. It is an animation that will be as the background. (image.png=>1600x350=>5 images are linked horizontally). Thanks.

**Solution:**
initialize `currentFrame = tmp[0][0];`

Comment: At first glance the code looks ok other than you can use the delta passed into act instead of getting it again with getDeltaTime(). What results are you getting? Is it drawing anything at all?

Comment: Hi, in the game, I 'm adding actors on stage and there is no problem, when I add this actor, the game freezes and I get an error "RuntimeException".

Comment: I tried what you tell me but it does not work. the change you propose, is this? stateTime += delta;            Thank you very much.

Comment: yes, use stateTime += delta; although this is not a fix, it is just an optimization because delta and Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() will be the same value.

What is the message from the RuntimeException? It will probably lead you to your answer.

Comment: The message: "Thread [lwjgl application] (suspended (exception nullpointerexception))"  I checked the declarations and initializations, and I can not find the problem. Thanks for answering spectacularbob.

Comment: There's no obvious null pointer in the code you posted. If you're using Eclipse, you can get a stack trace for where the nullpointer happened. When you get the Exception, just keep clicking continue until the program stops running, then there will be a stack trace in the console showing you where the Exception happened.

Comment: Sorry, the program locates the error in a line of other code, and I did not think it would be necessary to expose it. --->>            LwjglApplication$1.run() line:119

Comment: I added, above, the code that appears on the screen.

Comment: That code appears whenever you get an exception in libgdx. Keep hitting the continue button until the app terminates, then you will get call stack where the null exception is really happening

Comment: Thanks spectacularbob. I have resolved with: currentFrame = tmp[0][0];

Answer (score -1):

**Solution:** initialize `currentFrame = tmp[0][0];`

Comment: Why is that the solution?

Comment: "The NullPointerException occurs when an object is used for some action when the object itself is null because it likely hasn't been initialized." so the solution is initialize currentFrame.